# azure_rm_resourcegroup does work in azure cloud shell but not locallyq

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-aks

I am able to create a resource group with the following ansible playbook in the azure cloud shell, but not from my local pc. Why? I tried to recreate the application/secrets multiple times but nothing worked.

```
- name: Create Azure Kubernetes Service
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    resource_group: birdy71
    location: westeurope
    aks_name: birdy7-cluster
    username: birdy7
    ssh_key: "ssh-rsa xxxxxxxx"
    client_id: "xxxx"
    client_secret: "xxx"
    tenant: "xxx"
    subscription_id: "xxx"
  tasks:
  - name: Create resource group
    azure_rm_resourcegroup:
      name: "{{ resource_group }}"
      location: "{{ location }}"
      client_id: "{{ client_id }}"
      secret: "{{ client_secret }}"
      subscription_id: "{{ subscription_id }}"
      tenant: "{{ tenant }}"
```

In the azure cloud shell I removed the ~/.azure folder completely but it works nonetheless. On my local pc I get this error: AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.

But how can that be? The secret works well if it is used from within the azure cloud shell.

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: Timestamp: 2019-03-20 13: 34: 02Z
fatal: [localhost
]: FAILED! => {
  "changed": false,
  "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/Users/tobias/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553088840.81-75656009010434/AnsiballZ_azure_rm_resourcegroup.py\", line 113, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/Users/tobias/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553088840.81-75656009010434/AnsiballZ_azure_rm_resourcegroup.py\", line 105, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/Users/tobias/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553088840.81-75656009010434/AnsiballZ_azure_rm_resourcegroup.py\", line 48, in invoke_module\n    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\n  File \"/var/folders/fl/pps_zz4s3lx6569226xr_2bh0000gn/T/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload_CeouHT/__main__.py\", line 256, in <module>\n  File \"/var/folders/fl/pps_zz4s3lx6569226xr_2bh0000gn/T/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload_CeouHT/__main__.py\", line 252, in main\n  File \"/var/folders/fl/pps_zz4s3lx6569226xr_2bh0000gn/T/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload_CeouHT/__main__.py\", line 136, in __init__\n  File \"/var/folders/fl/pps_zz4s3lx6569226xr_2bh0000gn/T/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload_CeouHT/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py\", line 301, in __init__\n  File \"/var/folders/fl/pps_zz4s3lx6569226xr_2bh0000gn/T/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload_CeouHT/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py\", line 1021, in __init__\n  File \"/Users/tobias/.venv/azure2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrestazure/azure_active_directory.py\", line 453, in __init__\n    self.set_token()\n  File \"/Users/tobias/.venv/azure2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrestazure/azure_active_directory.py\", line 480, in set_token\n    raise_with_traceback(AuthenticationError, \"\", err)\n  File \"/Users/tobias/.venv/azure2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrest/exceptions.py\", line 48, in raise_with_traceback\n    raise error\nmsrest.exceptions.AuthenticationError: , InvalidClientError: (invalid_client) AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: c7fab593-93e7-415f-a3e8-5ba973e81e00\r\nCorrelation ID: 5ee1181d-f0ac-4c08-a0e7-dfba9c722073\r\nTimestamp: 2019-03-20 13:34:02Z\n",
  "module_stdout": "",
  "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
  "rc": 1
}
```

Comment: you need to auth to azure with az cli before hand, have you done that? or provide credentials in other way

Comment: Any more questions? Or if it's helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I can reappear the error that happened to you:

[image]

From the error it shows the core problem you meet:

> InvalidClientError: (invalid_client) AADSTS7000215: Invalid client
>   secret is provided.

So you must input the wrong secret of the service principal. For service principal secret, you just can see it when you create. So I suggest you can reset the secret through CLI command [`az ad sp credential reset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp/credential?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-credential-reset) if you really do not remember it.

Also, you can check if the secret of your service principal is right through the CLI command:

```
az login --service-principal --username APP_ID --password PASSWORD --tenant TENANT_ID
```

In addition, when you use the Cloud Shell to execute ansible, it means Automatic credential by Azure. See [Automatic credential configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ansible/ansible-run-playbook-in-cloudshell#automatic-credential-configuration)

> When signed into the Cloud Shell, Ansible authenticates with Azure to
>   manage infrastructure without any additional configuration.

The screenshot below is the result of my test:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to regenerate my client secret until I get one without special characters like "&" and "\". :-(

Comment: Are you sure about that? My secret also contains the character "@" and it works.